# Extract text from period delimited String rows in Pysprak

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

I need to extract a text from a String row items in pyspark. I have tried almost all options available but no luck.

```
Submission ID
Dx.CS1.2023-21-01
DX.RE1.2023-12-01
DX.G1.2021-23-01
DX.G2.2022-10-12
```

Desired Out:

```
ID
CS1
RE1
G1
G2
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the requirements are not particularly clear, suppose you need to separate by multiple separators (such as `spaces` and `dots` in the sample data) to obtain the **second position element**. Assuming the original field name is `col`, the solution is as follows:

```
df = df.select(F.split('col', ' |\\.')[1].alias('col'))
```